# Connecting DBeaver to a Firebird file, gives error code 335544721

Tags: sql, firebird, dbeaver

I'm trying to make DBeaver database manager connect to a Firebird *.FDB file. It is a local file database and I want to inspect the tables etc and perform some queries for data reporting.

However, when I try to open the database in DBeaver I get this error message:

> Unable to complete network request to host
>   "localhost".[SQLState:08006, ISC error code 335544721]
>   Connection refused: connect

[image: DBeaver cannot connect to Firebird database file]

I've tried updating the driver, which updates the `org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18:RELEASE [3.0.5]` without any errors, and also enabling/disabling the embedded checkbox.

As far as I know Firebird is supported by DBeaver, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

After some trial and error I've figured out the answer to this. The services `Firebird Service` and `Firebird Guardian` weren't running. I had installed the Firebird Server but accidentally selected "Run as an Application" instead of "Run as a Service".

[image: Firebird Server setup options select additional tasks]

DBeaver cannot connect to the Firebird database file without these services running. Which is kind of odd because the osFinancials application that uses this database file was working just fine without the services.

Anyway, once the Firebird Server is installed as "run as application" there is AFAIK no easy way to still get it to run as a service. So I just uninstalled and then reinstalled the Firebird Server setup and selected the correct option.

It adds two services named `FirebirdGuardianDefaultInstance` and `FirebirdServerDefaultInstance` which correspond to these two commandlines:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbguard.exe" -s DefaultInstance
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbserver.exe" -s DefaultInstance
```

Comment: I am trying to connect to remote server (db and file are on a server) and I am getting the same error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is it maybe behind a firewall? And is the port (probably port 3050) also accessable? Maybe it's easier to just install DBeaver application also on the server and run it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility of the version of the driver being incompatible with the version the (remote) server is using. You can try upgrading (or downgrading) the version by downloading the appropriate version:

[image: Dbeaver upgrade/downgrade driver version]

Answer (score -1):

Service "Firebird" must be active:

[image: Service "Firebird" must be active]

[image: image description]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).